# Elasticsearch script_fields with geo_shape

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use elasticsearch to annotate data with geographic belonging.

I'm quite new to elasticsearch so I'm a bit unsure about the correct word to search for. I might have missed an obvious answer, but I didn't find what I was looking for in the Elasticsearch documentation.

#### Problem description :

I have a huge set of events stored in a ElasticSearch database. I would like to query these events, and for each event, add a kind of scripted field telling is the event point is within a given polygon.

I should be able to do this with two queries :

- a first one retrieving a batch of events
- another one filtering the same events with a geo_shape filter
  I could then check for every event in the first list if it's also in the second one.

But it would be so much easier to have one query, with the event document annotated with an `is_within_polygon` boolean.
And it would also allow me to check against multiple polygons in one query.

Is it possible with Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Can you provide a quick example of what you're doing now?

Comment: Well.... I'm not doing enything yet ^^

Currently I query the events in a python code with elasticsearch-dsl, then for every event, I do the geographic calculation with python :
`geometry.covers(point)` where `geometry` is a `django.contrib.gis.geos.MultiPolygon` and point a `django.contrib.gis.geos.Point`

Comment: Can you show what you're doing in Python, especially the second phase (not the query)?

Comment: I updated the previous comment that I added before finishing typing it

Comment: Are the point(s) that you're checking different everytime or is it always the same?

Comment: I have millions of events, each with a different gps coordinates.

I need to make calculations on some gevent queryset matching criterias (for example, only events between the 1rst and 3rd of January, only events from a given source, etc).

Every calculation then process the events and check if it's coordinate is in a given geojson describing an area. So the points and the area are different every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217016/discussion-between-tonial-and-val).